# Shift register m74hc165 connection

Tags: arduino

I am following the following tutorial (http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShiftIn) to connect a shift-in register to my Arduino. In the tutorial they use a CD4021 'CD4021' shift register and I got a 'm74hc165'. After looking at the datasheet (http://www.datasheetlib.com/datasheet/735260/m74hc165b1_sgs-thomson-microelectronics.html#datasheet) I cannot figure out how to connect the following wires:

```
Q8 (pin 3) to Ardunio DigitalPin 9 (blue wire)
CLOCK (pin 10) to to Ardunio DigitalPin 7 (yellow wire)
P/S C (pin 9) to Ardunio DigitalPin 8 (green wire)
```

Mentioned in the tutorial in section 2. Can somebody help me with how to connect these three wires to the shift-register?

Comment: migration not possible towards http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino ? though I think this belong to there, rather than here.

Comment: I search for Arduino on stackoverflow, next time I will search on stackexchange to locate the right place to ask the question. I have posted the question there, thank you for the reply. The question may be deleted to prevent contamination.

Comment: This question appears to be more suited for http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Several years later, but hope it helps.

According to the data sheets, the 74165 has the following equivalences to the CD4021:

- `Q8` would be `Qh` (pin 9) in the 165. The 4021 has three outputs for the last three stages of the shift register. The 165 has only one: `Qh`.
- `CLOCK` would be `CLK` (pin 2) in the 165. But `CLK INH` must be low (wired to GND). This is used to inhibit the clock, something we don't want in most of the setups, including the Arduino example.
- `P/S C` would be `SH/^LD` (pin 1). But caution. In the 165, the logic is inverted. A HIGH value means the data can be shifted, and a LOW value the parallel data must be latched. The CD4021 is the other way around: HIGH means latch the parallel data and LOW let the bits shift serially.

All this obtained from [this more recent data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc165.pdf).